# How to execute command on parent window by User control button?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, user-controls, command

I want to make reusable jog user control. I added usercontrol on the main window.

I want to make like this
usercontrol button clicked -> 'UpJogClickCommand' call 'UpJogRelayCommand' -> execute method(UpJogMove)

But my code is Not working.. when i click button, main code do not execute 'UpJogMove'

[JogButtonControl.xaml]

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <Button Command="{Binding UpJogClickCommand}">
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

[JogButtonControl.xaml.cs]

```
public partial class JogButtonControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty UpJogClickCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "UpJogClickCommand",
            typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(JogButtonControl));
    public ICommand UpJogClickCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(UpJogClickCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UpJogClickCommandProperty, value); }
    }
    public JogButtonControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

[MainWindow.xaml]

```
<StackPanel x:Name="TempSP" Grid.Column="7">
    <JogControl:JogButtonControl UpJogClickCommand="{Binding Path=UpJogRelayCommand}"
</StackPanel>
```

[MainWindow.xaml.cs]

```
private RelayCommand<object> _upJogRelayCommand;
public ICommand UpJogRelayCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_upJogRelayCommand == null)
        {
            _upJogRelayCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(UpJogMove);
        }
        return _upJogRelayCommand;
    }
}
private void UpJogMove(object notUsed)
{
    Debug.Print("UpJogExcuted():");
    MoveToUpDirection();
}
```

Comment: I don't see any code that sets the `JogButtonControl.UpJogClickCommand` property value. If it's not simply that you've forgotten to set the property value, you need to provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. Also, be more specific about _what_ the problem is. What _exactly_ does the code do, what do you want instead, what have you tried so far to fix it, and what _specifically_ are you still having trouble with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify the source object of the Binding in the XAML of your UserControl, e.g. by setting the `RelativeSource` property:

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <Button Command="{Binding UpJogClickCommand,
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
   </Grid>
</UserControl>
```